# Design pattern for different xml writers

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a general import class that takes input from an api.

The import takes in products and categories and writes them to xml files. The trouble is the xml files are structure differently for produtcs and categories in 2 ways:

1. The opening tag is different and has different namespaces
2. Each node is slightly different

What would be a good design pattern to use here?

I currently have:

```
Importer
XmlWriter
    Product
    Category
```

Is there anything else i should be thinking of here?

Answer (score 0):

In this case I only think of the StrategyPattern combined with a creational method or factory pattern. Pseudo source below.

```
public class Importer {

    private <T> XMLWriter getWriter(T entity){
        // Returns an instance from ProductXMLWriter of CategoryXMLWriter
        return Factory.createXmlWriter(entity);
    }

    public <T> String entityToXML(T entity){
        return getWriter(entity).entityToString();
    }

}


public interface XmlWriter<T extends Entity> {  
   public String entityToString();
}


public class ProductXmlWriter implements XmlWriter {
    ...
}


public class CategoryXmlWriter implements XmlWriter {
    ...
}
```